# Can' npm install from the root folder

Tags: npm

When I try to npm install from the root folder I get an error, this is the script from the root folder

```
"scripts": {
    "install-API": "npm install --prefix API",
    "install-client": "npm install --prefix client",
    "install": "npm run install-API && npm run install-client ",
    "deploy": "set BUILD_PATH=../API/public && npm run build --prefix client && npm start --prefix API ",
    "deploy-cluster": "npm run build --prefix client && npm run cluster --prefix API",
    "API": "npm run watch --prefix API",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
     },
```

but if I cd into either folder I can npm install without problems this is the error I get is very long so I will just post a portion [image]

Comment: Looks like an infinite recursion. The `install` script calls `npm run install-API`, then `install-API` calls `npm install`?

Comment: No, the npm install calls the npm run install-api. Anyway if I just npm run install-api or client the same error happens

Comment: According to your scripts, what it looks like is: if you do `npm run install-API`,  it will call `npm install --prefix API`. This "npm install --prefix API"` will then call `npm run install-API && npm run install-client`. The first part is `npm run install-API` (again) so it is infinitely recursive.

Comment: no, npm install --prefix API will not call npm run install-API && npm run install-client, the prefix is so that it looks in the API folder so it would only install on the API folder